# SQL Server GROUP BY show only first match

Tags: sql-server

I have the following table and want to group by

```
[name]             [phone]
doniking           081222222222
doni               081222222222
Bambang Gentholet  081111111111
Bambang            081111111111
```

I want to get this result:

```
[name]             [phone]
doniking           081222222222
Bambang Gentholet  081111111111
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
SELECT [name],[phone] 
FROM (
      SELECT *,Row_Number() Over (Partition By phone Order By (Select Null)) AS RN
      FROM Table1
      ) AS T
Where RN = 1
OFFSET n ROWS
```

You can replace n with your custom values...

[**Row_Number**](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx)

Comment: if i add a column type date, how to get the name based on the newest date?

Comment: how do I apply OFFSET to that query?

Comment: [**Check this Link**](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg699618.aspx) Check my updated answer

Comment: forgot to say that i am using sql2005

Answer (score 4):

Try this

```
SELECT MAX(name), phone  FROM <TableName> group by phone
```

EDIT: for offset

```
SELECT MAX(name), phone  FROM <TableName> group by phone
order by phone offset 10 rows 
FETCH NEXT 5 ROWS ONLY;
```

[Check this](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg699618.aspx) for further details.

Comment: how do I apply OFFSET to that query?

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
SELECT name, 
   phone 
FROM  (SELECT *, 
          Row_number() 
            OVER( 
              partition BY phone 
              ORDER BY name) row_num -- or you can have order by (select null)
   FROM   table1) t 
WHERE  row_num = 1
```

Comment: how do I apply OFFSET to that query?

Comment: what do you mean by apply OFFSET? Can you elaborate what you are looking for?

Comment: i am going to page the results which needs LIMIT and OFFSET. unfortunately my SQL2005 doesnt support OFFSET keyword.

Comment: So do you want to apply the limit and offset only to your final result or before filtering out the duplicates?